# how to fetch data in view or display it in a page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my profile.php code i want to display it in webpage

```
<!-- Bridegroom Profile Details -->
<div class="w3ls-list">

    <div class="container">

                <h2>Bridegroom Profile Details</h2>

    <div class="col-md-9 profiles-list-agileits">
        <div class="single_w3_profile">
            <div class="agileits_profile_image">
    <?php foreach ($profile_details as $row) { ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $row['upload'];?>" alt="profile image" />
                                           <?php } ?>

            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="profile_w3layouts_details">

            <div class="agileits_aboutme">
                <h4>Profile</h4>
                <h5>Personal Details:</h5>
                <div class="form_but1">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label1" for="Relation">Profile for : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 w3_details">

                                               <!--Brother--> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form_but1">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label1" for="Relation">Name : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 w3_details">

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form_but1">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label1" for="Relation">Gender : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 w3_details">

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
                                    <div class="form_but1">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label1" for="Relation">Dob : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 w3_details">

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
                                    <div class="form_but1">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label1" for="Relation">Religion : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 w3_details">

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
                                    <div class="form_but1">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label1" for="Relation">Mobile : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 w3_details">

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                    </div>


                            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
           </div>    

    </div>
```

this is my controller home.php 
please help to how to diplay this profile

```
 public function profile($param1='')
 {  

     //$data['user_detail'] = $this->db->get_where('admin',array('id'=> $this->session->userdata('admin_id')))->result_array();
     $data['page_name']='profile';
     $data['profile_details']=$this->db->get_where('profile',array('id' => $param1))->result_array();

     $this->load->view('index',$data);
 }
```

Comment: What is the actual issue? You seem to know how to show views and pass data? Just do it the same way for your profile? I you don't understand the code, you should really read CI's documentation about views.

Comment: shown code of `profile.php` and calling `index` in `view` ??

Comment: long time doubt !!!  :    where these people are gone after question posted here ??

Comment: you don't need foreach here try my answer .

Comment: Why you fire a query form `controller`, If you are using MVC they try to follow the basic rules.  I know it's not mandatory but you should use your query in `model`

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know to do this

```
<?php foreach ($profile_details as $row) { ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $row['upload'];?>" alt="profile image" />
<?php } ?>
```

I think what you want to do is like below?

```
 <div class="form_but1">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label1" for="Relation">Name : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 w3_details">
                         <?php echo $row['Name'];?> // or the name of the column
                    </div>
     <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>
```

### Added

Put a `print_r($data)` after your database query and check if you actually getting a result.

```
public function profile($param1='')
 {  

     //$data['user_detail'] = $this->db->get_where('admin',array('id'=> $this->session->userdata('admin_id')))->result_array();
     $data['page_name']='profile';
     $data['profile_details']=$this->db->get_where('profile',array('id' => $param1))->result_array();

    print_r($data);

     $this->load->view('index',$data);


 }
```

Comment: when i try to do like this error shows like this   A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: row

Filename: views/profile.php

Line Number: 38

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\match\application\views\profile.php
Line: 38
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\match\application\views\index.php
Line: 36
Function: include

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\match\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 107
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\match\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Can you put a print_r($data) on your home.php and see if you actually having a result.

Answer (score 0):

Since Your fetching `single record` so no need `foreach` here simple do like this

```
<?php if(isset($profile_details[0]['upload'])) { ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $profile_details[0]['upload'];?>" alt="profile image" >
<?php } ?>
```

and

```
 <div class="form_but1">
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label1" for="Relation">Name : </label>
         <div class="col-sm-9 w3_details">
               <?php if(isset($profile_details[0]['Name'])) { 
                            echo $profile_details[0]['Name'];
                 } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper Way to fetch data in view or display it in a page in CodeIgniter:

if you know that you are fetching a single record use `row_array` instead of `result_array`. Use `result_array` only when you know that you are fetchig multiple rows form database.

Your Model:

```
public function get_single_profile($param1)
{
        $query = $this->db
                ->select('*')
                ->where('id', $param1)      
                ->get('profile');
        $profile_data = $query->row_array();
        return $profile_data;
}
```

In Controller:
    Load Model in the `__construct`

```
    public function profile($param1)
    {
        $this->load->model ('your_model');
        $profile_data = $this->your_model->get_single_profile ($param1);

        $this->load->view ('index',['profile_data' => $profile_data]);
    }
```

On the view Page:

```
<?php if(isset($profile_data) && !empty($profile_data)){ ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $profile_data['upload'];?>" alt="profile image" />
    //And So on...

<?php } ?>
```